# Сохранить картинку в base64 без альфа канала

Tags: c#, изображения

Есть строка в формате base64. Это изображение. Сохраняя его, у меня остается черный фон сзади. В paint его я не вижу. Скорее всего это альфа канал. Как сохранить изображение без него?

```
 public Image Base64ToImage()
        {
            // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
            // Convert byte[] to Image
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
            {
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                return image;
            }
        }

 var img= Base64ToImage();
 img.Save("checknew.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, в этом изображении альфа-канал у всех пикселов равен 0 - полностью прозрачный.

Каждый просмотрщик изображений при отрисовке такого изображения поступает по-своему: фон может быть чёрным, белым или каким-либо ещё. В частности, метод `Graphcis.DrawImage` отрисовывает с просвечивающим фоном контрола, на который идёт отрисовка. Задайте свойство `BackColor` красным - и фон будет соответствующим.

Сделать изображение непрозрачным можно следующим кодом:

```
var bmp = (Bitmap)img;

for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
    {
        var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        // 255 - полностью непрозрачный альфа-канал
        color = Color.FromArgb(255, color);
        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, color);
    }
}
```

Все пикселы будут сделаны непрозрачными, а цвет останется прежним, то есть фон чёрный, цифры - серые.

Однако, проблема вот в чём. В этом изображении при помощи полупрозрачности сделано сглаживание. И после такой конвертации оно станет "рубленым", более грубым.

Чтобы избежать этого, можно сделать непрозрачными только чёрные пикселы, не затрагивая цифры со сглаживанием:

```
var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
if (color.R == 0 && color.G == 0 && color.B == 0)
{
    color = Color.Black; // непрозрачный чёрный
    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, color);
}
```

Такое изображение будет казаться "гладким", но только при выводе на чёрный (тёмный) фон. При выводе на белый (светлый) или цветной фон вид будет очень плохим.

Естественно, цвет можно задать любым:

```
color = Color.White; // непрозрачный белый
```

Теперь на белом фоне всё будет красиво, но на чёрном - грубо.

Выбирайте, что вам больше подойдёт.

Естественно, можно полностью убрать прозрачность и одновременно изменить фон картинки:

```
var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
if (color.R == 0 && color.G == 0 && color.B == 0)
{
    color = Color.White; // меняем цвет фона (выберите нужный)
    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, color);
}
else
    // цвет цифр остаётся, но становится непрозрачным
    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, color));
```

Тогда изображение будет одинаково "рубленым" при выводе на любой фон. Но всегда приемлемо читаемым.

---

Методы `GetPixel`, `SetPixel` очень медленные. На такой маленькой картинке это неощутимо, но при желании можно во много раз ускорить код, использовав технику с применением [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var bmp = (Bitmap)img;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;

byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 4)
{
    if (rgbValues[counter] == 0 && rgbValues[counter + 1] == 0 && rgbValues[counter + 2] == 0)
    {
        rgbValues[counter] = 255; // blue
        rgbValues[counter + 1] = 255; // green
        rgbValues[counter + 2] = 255; // red
        rgbValues[counter + 3] = 255; // alpha
    }
}
Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Данное изображение 32-битное, то есть 4 байта на пиксел. Поэтому шаг в цикле равен 4.

Ну и на заедочку, вариант с указателями. Теоретически, он ещё быстрей.

```
var bmp = (Bitmap)img;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;

unsafe
{
    byte* b = (byte*)ptr.ToPointer();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i += 4, b += 4)
    {
        if (*b == 0 && *(b + 1) == 0 && *(b + 2) == 0)
        {
            *b = 255; // blue
            *(b + 1) = 255; // green
            *(b + 2) = 255; // red
            *(b + 3) = 255; // alpha
        }
    }
}

bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

В настройках проекта (Project > Properties > Build) при этом нужно разрешить небезопасный код (Allow unsafe code).