# Поясните, как работать с LockBits классом

Tags: c#, winforms

В своём проекте я использую изображения большого разрешения, из-за чего методы getpixel/setpixel работают  очень медленно, то-есть програма лагает, но работает, ошибок нет. Погуглил, что есть много способов их ускорить, но мне они не понятны. Может кто-то предложить способ ускорить работу методов getpixel/setpixel и подробно объяснить его?

```
    //объявление битмапов
    public static Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
    public static Bitmap myBitmapScale1 = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
    public static Bitmap myBitmapScale2 = new Bitmap("img\\BigMapScale2.png");
```

```
   public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //получение цвета нажатого пикселя
           MouseEventArgs rato = e as MouseEventArgs;
           int x = rato.X * myBitmap.Width / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
           int y = rato.Y * myBitmap.Height / pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
           Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
           string hex = backColor.R.ToString("X2") + backColor.G.ToString("X2") + backColor.B.ToString("X2");
         }
```

```
//поиск всех пикселей определённого цвета и замена на DarkGray
    private void darkmode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < myBitmap.Width; x++)
                for (var y = 0; y < myBitmap.Height; y++)
                {
                    var pixel = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    if (pixel.R == 176 && pixel.G == 244 && pixel.B == 254)
                        myBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.DarkGray);
 
                }
            
        }
```

Comment: По приведенной вами же ссылке есть раздел Usage. Вы его читали?

Comment: Читал, но как мне использовать класс, если при его добавлении у меня куча ошибок выходит. Скорее всего сам класс надо редактировать под свой проект.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет проще разобраться с примером из документации: [Bitmap.LockBits Метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Начните изучение языка с более простых задач.

Comment: aepot, я бы с радостью, но нет времени. Вынужден делать проект на языке, которого не знаю

Comment: В таком случае, конкретизируйте вопрос, приведите ваш код, который возвращает ошибку, покажите текст ошибки, и опишите, что вы пытаетесь сделать как можно подробнее: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: Отредактировал код и оставил в нём те места, из-за которых происходят лаги. Воспроизводимую програму предоставить не могу, ибо для неё требуются дополнительные ресурсы. И сам вопрос переформулировал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код скопирован из документации: [Bitmap.LockBits Метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8), очищен от комментариев и пространств имён. В итоге он становится компактным и понятным.

Единственно, что может потребовать изменения - шаг изменения переменной `counter`. Если пиксельный формат изображения равен 32bpp (bit per pixel), этот шаг равен 4 байтам. Если формат 24 бита на пиксель, то шаг нужно изменить на 3, соответственно. И т. п.

Как узнать, какой формат у вашего изображения? Смотрите свойство [PixelFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.pixelformat?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_PixelFormat). Например, просто выведите его куда-нибудь: `this.Text = myBitmap.PixelFormat.ToString();`.
Конечно же, следует предусмотреть в коде изменение шага в зависимости от этого свойства (надеюсь сообразите как добавить `if`).

```
private void darkmode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);

    BitmapData bmpData = myBitmap.LockBits(
        rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, myBitmap.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * myBitmap.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 4)
    {
        if (
            rgbValues[counter] == 254 && // blue
            rgbValues[counter + 1] == 244 && // green
            rgbValues[counter + 2] == 176 // red
            )
        {
            rgbValues[counter] = Color.DarkGray.B;
            rgbValues[counter + 1] = Color.DarkGray.G;
            rgbValues[counter + 2] = Color.DarkGray.R;
        }
    }

    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
    myBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

---

Можно ещё ускорить код, используя указатели - это избавит от копирования массива. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549857/184217

Также весьма быстрые преобразования цвета позволяет класс [ColorMatrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=netframework-4.8). Обратите на него внимание.