# Оптимизация функции, которая красит Bitmap

Tags: c#, оптимизация, bitmap

У меня есть функция которая красит Bitmap в заданный мной цвет с учётом прозрачности. По замерам Stopwatch покраска Bitmap`a 700x300 занимает целых 150мс! Можно ли как-то увеличить производительность этого?

```cs
// System.Drawing.Bitmap и System.Drawing.Color
public static unsafe Bitmap GetColoredBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
{
    if (bitmap == null)
        return null;
    BitmapData bitmapdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    int* pointer = (int*)bitmapdata.Scan0.ToPointer();
    int num = 0;
    while (num < bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height)
    {
         if ((*pointer & 0xff000000) > 0)
         {
              *pointer = Color.FromArgb(Color.FromArgb(*pointer).A, color).ToArgb();
         }
         ++num;
         ++pointer;
    }
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: а в разных потоках красить можно?

Comment: Один рисунок в разных потоках? Если это будет оптимизировать выполнение, то, наверно, да.

Comment: StopWatch правильно используется? Времени действительно затрачено много. Попробуйте выяснить, что именно затратно. Например, 1) ничего не делать внутри LockBits  2) заполнять константой

Comment: Вызовы методов `FromArgb`, `ToArgb()` можно устранить. Можно менять байты напрямую через указатель.

Comment: Кроме распараллеливания можно ещё попробовать применить SIMD. Но это только на .NET Core / .NET 5. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1219811/184217

Comment: И ещё один совет: использовать какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку для работы с графикой.

Comment: Stopwatch используется правильно. Я тут выяснил, что даже просто цикл без всего, кроме ++num занимает всё то же время.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не подскажете, как заменить эти методы на указатели?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549857/184217 - см. в конце

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как по мне, так распараллеливание при затратах на целую операцию менее 30мс не имеет никакого смысла, потому что многопоточный оверхед скушает больше времени, чем принесет пользы. А вот SIMD - да, вещь отличная!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот эти 2 варианта.

Это важно

> `Stride` имеет выравнивание 4 байт и всегда кратный 4, независимо от количества байт на пиксель. Например представьте ширину картинки 3 пикселя при 3 байт на пиксель, `Stride` будет 12. То есть первый пиксель второй строки будет иметь индекс 12, а не 9. Поэтому ARGB удобнее, оно всегда выровнено. А еще `Stride` может быть отрицательным, если битмап был сохранен для загрузки снизу-вверх (да, такое тоже бывает).

Этот вариант будет быстрее работать для картинок, у которых базово нет прозрачности. Быстрее, потому что GDI+ не придется преобразовывать данные битмапа.

```cs
public unsafe void SetBitmapColor24(Bitmap bmp, Color color)
{
    int width = bmp.Width;
    int height = bmp.Height;
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = bmpData.Stride;
    byte* pos = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
    byte r = color.R;
    byte g = color.G;
    byte b = color.B;
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            byte* offset = pos + rowOffset + col * 3;
            *(offset + 2) = r;
            *(offset + 1) = g;
            *offset = b;
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Этот вариант будет быстрее работать для картинок с прозрачностью, с сохранением прозрачности.

```cs
public unsafe void SetBitmapColor32(Bitmap bmp, Color color)
{
    int width = bmp.Width;
    int height = bmp.Height;
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    uint* pos = (uint*)bmpData.Scan0;
    uint argb = (uint)color.ToArgb() & 0xffffff;
    int strideWidth = bmpData.Stride >> 2;
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        uint* rowOffset = pos + strideWidth * row;
        for (uint* offset = rowOffset; offset < rowOffset + width; offset++)
        {
            *offset = *offset & 0xff000000 | argb;
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Обратите внимание, я не возвращаю битмап значением из метода. Потому что меняется именно исходный битмап.

Comment: Мне необходимо было менять цвет, не изменяя оригинальной прозрачности. То есть, если изначально был цвет пикселя (125, 60, 60, 60), а я передал цвет (255, 100,100,100), то цвет пикселя будет (125,100,100,100)

Comment: @Cordis если вам интересно, как это сделать еще быстрее - [загляните сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567). Не простой фильтр применяется к 2560x1440 картинке, при этом картинка сначала обесцвечивается, а только потом фильтруется,  и всё это за 5мс.

Comment: @Cordis что там по скорости получилось? Для 1кк пикселей подозреваю ~20мс или даже меньше.

Comment: В среднем получается около 7мс. Относительно моего куска кода вышло на +-2мс меньше. При прогоне через 100 итераций получается в среднем на 150мс меньше

Comment: @Cordis попробуйте мерять время 1) в релизной сборке (галочка "оптимизировать код" включена) 2) используя Benchmark.NET. Без первого пункта измерения не имеют смысла.

Comment: В какой-то момент я был слишком близко к текущему результату, но как дурак не догадался использовать оператор |, и полез сюда :с

Comment: @Cordis если вам важна производительность, переезжайте на .NET 5 (если вы еще не там), и пробуйте SIMD. Если не будет получаться, создайте здесь новый вопрос, помогу как увижу.

Comment: Если с релизом, то получается около 1.7мс за 1 и +-170мс за 100 итераций. Старый ответ выдаёт около 2.4 и 240. Для меня такой производительности уже достаточно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Cordis еще чуть поиздевался над кодом. Вряд-ли стало быстрее, но не медленнее точно.

Answer (score 3):

Оказывается в этой строчке каждый раз дважды происходило получение свойства bitmap, из-за чего время выполнения увеличивалось в пару(5-6) раз.

```cs
while (num < bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height)
```

Замена на такой вариант выдала уже около 25мс

```cs
int size = bitmapdata.Width * bitmapdata.Height;
while (num < size)
```

Далее было найдено удивительно простое решение - вместо int* использовать byte*, что позволило бы избавиться от методов класса Color. В сумме получилась вот такая красота:

```cs
if (bitmap == null) 
    return null;

BitmapData bitmapdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
byte* pointer = (byte*) bitmapdata.Scan0.ToPointer();
int num = 0;
int size = bitmapdata.Width * bitmapdata.Height;
byte r = color.R;
byte g = color.G;
byte b = color.B;
while (num < size) 
{
    if ( * (pointer + 3) > 0) 
    { 
        *(pointer + 2) = r; 
        *(pointer + 1) = g; 
        *pointer = b;
    }
    ++num;
    pointer += 4;
}
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);

return bitmap;
```

Bitmap размером 512x512 проходит за 1.5 мс.
Bitmap размером 1024x1024 за 7 мс

Comment: `каждый раз происходило умножение` вероятно, дело не в умножении, а в получении свойства объекта.

Comment: ну да) именно так

Comment: Ещё лучше будет заменить тяжеловесные свойства `Bitmap.Width` и `Bitmap.Height` на гораздо более лёгкие `BitmapData.Width` и `BitmapData.Height`.

Comment: Опытным путём выяснил, что свойство Stride здесь не понадобилось, а формат цвета получился 0xBBGGRRAA

Comment: Это будет работать только если используется формат 4 байта на пиксель, то есть я рекомендую явно задавать `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, в противном случае если вам попадется битмап с другим форматом, ваш алгоритм сломается об выравнивание данных в битмапе. Другими словами `Stride` имеет выравнивание и всегда кратный 4, независимо от количества байт на пиксель. Например представьте ширину картинки 3 пикселя при 3 байт на пиксель, `Stride` будет 12. То есть первый пиксель будет иметь индекс 12, а не 9, как бы вы ожидали.

Comment: Я могу написать код, который покрасит битмап 1024x1024 менее, например чем за миллисекунду. Надо?

Comment: @aepot Это было бы неплохо